# Dynamically enabling / disabling a GameObjects script component based on a string of the class name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to enable/ disable a script on a UnityEngine `GameObject` dynamically based on a string of the class name.

I am looping through a list of strings (the class names) and trying to get the script component on the gameObject using `gameObject.GetComponent()`.

My method:

```
private void changeWeaponScript(int weaponIndex) {
    if (weaponInventory.ElementAtOrDefault(weaponIndex) != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < weaponInventory.Count; i++) {
            if (weaponInventory[i] != weaponInventory[weaponIndex]) {
                if (weaponInventory[i] != null) {
                    Debug.Log("disable " + weaponInventory[i]);
                    (GetComponent(weaponInventory[weaponIndex]) as MonoBehaviour).enabled = false;
                }
            } 
        }

        Debug.Log("enable " + weaponInventory[weaponIndex]);
        (GetComponent(weaponInventory[weaponIndex]) as MonoBehaviour).enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I have also tried getting the type using `Type.GetType`:

```
Type weaponClass = Type.GetType(weaponInventory[i]);
gameObject.GetComponent(weaponClass).enabled = false;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're looking for is "Reflection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Reflection to get all the types of subclasses of a given type, and filter those out by a string matching their partial or full name.

In this example I'll get the types of all MonoBehaviour's matching a given string as an IEnumerable. You can then use Unity's functions, such as FindObjectByType, GetComponent, AddComponent, and Destroy to get, create or destroy these components.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

// ... in some function
string partialClassName = "Sword"; // does not include namespace
string superClassType = typeof(MonoBehaviour); // type of superclass
List<Type> types = superClassType.Assembly.GetTypes()
.Where(t => t.Name == partialClassName && t.IsSubclassOf(superClassType) 
&& !t.IsAbstract).ToList();

// types are now a List<type> of subclasses of MonoBehaviour that match 
//  the "class" name Sword
```